# Change BottomNavigationView Icons on Back Button clicked

Tags: java, android, xml

At the bottom of my layout I have a **BottomNavigationView** with three fragments. If I click the back button the fragment is switching but not the bottom icons. How can I fix it?
addToBackStack() works. Maybe you have some advise to pretty the code.
 Is it good practise to have the fragment tags in the activity or fragment?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView;
    private static final String HOME_FRAGMENT = "homeFragment";
    private static final String SEARCH_FRAGMENT = "searchFragment";
    private static final String SHARE_FRAGMENT = "shareFragment";
    private boolean isFirstFragment;
    private long mBackPressedTime;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            init();
            setBottomNavigationView();
        }

        private void init() {
            mBottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

            mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            mBackPressedTime = 0;
        }

        private void setBottomNavigationView() {
            setFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance(), HOME_FRAGMENT);
            isFirstFragment = true;
            mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.ic_home:
                            setFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance(), HOME_FRAGMENT);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.ic_search:
                            setFragment(SearchFragment.newInstance(), SEARCH_FRAGMENT);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.ic_circle:
                            setFragment(ShareFragment.newInstance(), SHARE_FRAGMENT);
                            return true;

                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void setFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
            if (isFirstFragment) {
                transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
            }
            transaction.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            final long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                mFragmentManager.popBackStack();
            } else if (currentTimeMillis - mBackPressedTime > 2000) {
                mBackPressedTime = currentTimeMillis;
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.reach_homescreen), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Hans Baum instead of adding your first fragment to back stack try this code,

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mBottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId () != R.id.ic_home)
        {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.ic_home);
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }     
    }
```

This code will exit your activity if you are in Home Fragment else if you are in any other Fragment it will go to Home Fragment.
So no addToBackStack() needed. So your serFragment() method should be,

```
  private void setFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

hope it helps.
Note that in your code you never assigned false to isFirstFragment so i assume all fragments are added to backstack which is very memory consuming.

**UPDATE**:
Since your requirement is different.As you want **Instagra**m like tabs, i hope this implementation helps you .

```
    Deque<Integer> mStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    boolean isBackPressed  = false;

    private void setBottomNavigationView() {
        mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.ic_home:
                         if(!isBackPressed) {
                           pushFragmentIntoStack(R.id.ic_home);
                       }
                        isBackPressed = false
                        setFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance(), HOME_FRAGMENT);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.ic_search:
                        if(!isBackPressed) {
                           pushFragmentIntoStack(R.id.ic_search);
                       }
                        isBackPressed = false
                        setFragment(SearchFragment.newInstance(), SEARCH_FRAGMENT);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.ic_circle:
                        if(!isBackPressed) {
                           pushFragmentIntoStack(R.id.ic_circle);
                       }
                        isBackPressed = false
                        setFragment(ShareFragment.newInstance(), SHARE_FRAGMENT);
                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
        mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new 
              BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            }
        });
     mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.ic_home);
     pushFragmentIntoStack(R.id.ic_home);
    }

    private void pushFragmentIntoStack(int id)
    {
        if(mStack.size() < 3)
        {
            mStack.push(id);
        }
        else
        {
            mStack.removeLast();
            mStack.push(id);
        }
    }

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mStack.size() > 1)
        {
            isBackPressed = true;
            mStack.pop();
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(mStack.peek());
        }
        else 
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

I have used deque to store the order in which the tabs are clicked Since there are 3 tabs deque size is 3 .On back press it will pop the stack and go to that tab. If no item in stack it will quit the activity.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** 
Do not add fragments to backstack in this scenario because as i switch the tabs the backstack count will keep increasing and may even lead to MemoryOutOfBound exception.

**To Question 2:**
Coming to your Fragment tag question , It is good to save tag in fragment . As the fragment is reusable in any activity instead adding tag in every activity it is used , it is good if we add it in fragment itself.

Comment: where should I assign isFirstFragment = false; ?

Comment: I would like to have the backbutton like the instagram app. It should look at the top of the stack and switch to that fragment

Comment: As I assume adding only the home fragment to backStack is your intention you should have did like this 
`case R.id.ic_home:
                            
setFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance(), HOME_FRAGMENT);
                            
isFirstFragment = false
                            
return true;`

Comment: But if you follow the answer which proposed you will never need this isFirstFragment variable itself.Just try it :)

Comment: oops then it becomes bit tricky and my ans won't work. It works if your desired behaviour is whenever i click back it have to go to home and then exit.

Comment: I want every fragment in backStack. The BackButton should call the last fragment where I were.

Comment: @HansBaum I have updated my answer please see if it can help you.i have used a deque to store the order tabs are pressed  and on back press go to that tab . if No tab is in deque quit the activity

Comment: it doesn't work always. It works only if I tab back and forth.

Comment: updated (Y)  try now it must work.update the codes i changed in onBackPressed() method

Comment: it calls only the last fragment and at the beginning it does not work. But hey thanks. I see its hard to handle these kind of operations.

Comment: if I open the app an switch from first to second and click the backbutton it doesnt go back. (I will accept your answer)

Comment: ya ans updated adding `pushFragmentIntoStack(R.id.ic_home);` above `isFirstFragment = true;` in `setBottomNavigationView()` method should solve the issue. ya do accept.

Comment: nice. but it calls only the last fragment. How to call the last fragments in stack?

Comment: sorry i could not understand what you mean by last fragment in stack?

Comment: for example: I switch from fragment 1 to fragment 2 and from fragment 2 to fragment 3. If I click the backbutton it goes from 3 to 2 but not from 2 to 1.

Comment: @HansBaum updated the answer to recognise and avoid reselected tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(navigation_bottom.getSelectedItemId () != R.id.action_home)
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = 
        ((HomeActivity)this).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout_home, new HomeFragment());
        transaction.commit();
        navigation_bottom.setSelectedItemId(R.id.action_home);
    }
    else
    {
        HomeActivity.this.finishAffinity();
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the fragment name in the backstack with the fragment transaction

```
        getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame, YourCurrentFragment.newInstance())
            .addToBackStack(YourFragment.class.getName())
            .commit();
```

Then you can add onBackstackChangedListener to get the currently selected fragment

```
fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            FragmentManager.BackStackEntry bse = fragmentManager.
                    getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() -1);
            //bse will be the backstack entry for current fragment
            if (bse.getName().equals(YourFragment.class.getName())) {
                navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
            } else if (bse.getName().equals(YourSecondFragment.class.getName())) {
                navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question.

If you are reading this from the future, and using Navigation Component, this is a declarative way (automatically) to update the bottom icons when page is getting changed.

Based on this documentation [Update UI components with NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui).
Unless Google made any change again

**First**, [Tie destinations to menu items](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer)

it means, just provide android:id attribute's value to MenuItem same as the fragment of your <navigation>'s children

In the menu/your_menu_file.xml

```xml
<menu>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/navigation__fragment_home"
    android:title="@string/example_label_nav_home"/>
    
  <item
    android:id="@+id/navigation__fragment_about"
    android:title="@string/example_label_nav_about"/>
</menu>
```

In the navigation/your_navigation_file.xml

```html
<navigation>
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation__fragment_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_page_home"/>
    
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation__fragment_about"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_page_about"/>
</navigation>
```

**Second**, get the `NavHostFragment` to retrieve `NavController`
[based on this doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate)

```java
NavHostFragment navHostFragment =
        (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_FragmentContainerView);
NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
```

Better to place and save the `navHostFragment` and `navController` to the activity class, so you can reuse it.

**Last**, call setupWithNavController() for your `BottomNavigationView` (this is also for top app bar), [based on this doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui)

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNav, navController);
```

Now, actually you don't have to listen to any click event of the BottomNavigationView and back button event.

`BottomNavigationView` would automatically change the selected item, including navigation.