# How to highlight the corresponding fragment item icon in BottomNavigationView while clicking on backpress?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I am having a **BottomNavigationView** with **3** **item** tabs at the bottom of the screen.Each of the item tabs has **two fragments** in it. I am clicking on this flow, **Item1Fragment -> Item2Fragment -> Item3Fragment-> SubItem3Fragment1 -> SubItem3Fragment2**. So when I **backpress** from **Item3Fragment ,Item2Fragment** and **Item1Fragment's** coresponding item icons are highlighted.

I am referring this post [Change BottomNavigationView Icons on Back Button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325299/change-bottomnavigationview-icons-on-back-button-clicked)

What I need is when i backpress from **Item3Fragment** the flow should be  **SubItem3Fragment1(3rd Item icon Highlighted) -> Item3Fragment (3rd Item icon Highlighted)-> Item2Fragment (2nd Item icon Highlighted)->Item1Fragment (1st Item icon Highlighted)**

I am calling the SubItemFragments with
  **transaction.addToBackStack("subfrag");**

```
Deque<Integer> mStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
boolean isBackPressed  = false;

private void setBottomNavigationView() {
    mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.ic_home:
                     if(!isBackPressed) {
                       pushFragmentIntoStack(R.id.ic_home);
                   }
                    isBackPressed = false
                    setFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance(), HOME_FRAGMENT);
                    return true;
                case R.id.ic_search:
                    if(!isBackPressed) {
                       pushFragmentIntoStack(R.id.ic_search);
                   }
                    isBackPressed = false
                    setFragment(SearchFragment.newInstance(), SEARCH_FRAGMENT);
                    return true;
                case R.id.ic_circle:
                    if(!isBackPressed) {
                       pushFragmentIntoStack(R.id.ic_circle);
                   }
                    isBackPressed = false
                    setFragment(ShareFragment.newInstance(), SHARE_FRAGMENT);
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
    mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new 
          BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        }
    });
 mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.ic_home);
 pushFragmentIntoStack(R.id.ic_home);
}

private void pushFragmentIntoStack(int id)
{
    if(mStack.size() < 3)
    {
        mStack.push(id);
    }
    else
    {
        mStack.removeLast();
        mStack.push(id);
    }
}

private void setFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
    transaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mStack.size() > 1)
    {
        isBackPressed = true;
        mStack.pop();
        mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(mStack.peek());
    }
    else 
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this case by getting the **fragment name**, using the fragment name I am assigning the **id** for **tabItem**.Then using the **tabItem id**

```
 Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
 MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(tabId);
 menuItem.setChecked(true);
```